# Obout ComboBox not work with RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, combobox, obout

The Obout ComboBox, was used like bellow:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEndTipoEndereco" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlTipoEndereco"
    ValidationGroup="vagIndCad" ErrorMessage="Informe o tipo de endereço" ToolTip="Campo obrigatório">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <obout:ComboBox  ID="ddlTipoEndereco" runat="server"    EnableLoadOnDemand="True" 
        MenuWidth="150px" oninit="Init_ComboBox" Width="150px" ></obout:ComboBox>
```

But it is not working properly, is not validating when the selected value is "".

Which is equal to:
https://www.obout.com/interface/aspnet_integration_validators.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this Obout controls, but when using validators with DropDownLists you should set the InitialValue on the validator to the value you'd like to check against. For instance:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEndTipoEndereco" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="ddlTipoEndereco"  
ValidationGroup="vagIndCad" 
ErrorMessage="Informe o tipo de endereço" ToolTip="Campo obrigatório"
InitialValue="Select an item">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I believe the problem is because the initialValue of the obout ComboBox is -1, instead of 0